# Custom Delegate & DataSource NSObjects best practice

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

So consider this case, i have a `UIViewController` that contains a simple `UICollectionView`, but the `Delegate & DataSource` protocols are separated `NSObject`'s from the `UIViewController`.

It looks something like this

```
class MainCollctionViewDelegate: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate
class MainCollectionViewDataSrouce: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource
```

And i use them inside my `UIViewController` like this,

```
lazy var CVDelegate = MainCollctionViewDelegate()
lazy var CVDataSource = MainCollectionViewDataSrouce()
//MARK: - Life Cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.registerCell(PlainCell.self) // register custom cell Nib into collection View.
    collectionView.delegate = CVDelegate //Set Deleagte
    collectionView.dataSource = CVDataSource // Set data Source
}
```

Is this approach going to cause any memory leaks in the future ? considering i will implement an injection to fill the data source of the `CollectionView` to be something like this in the future.

```
 MainCollectionViewDataSrouce(with: Foo) // Foo is some data to populate the collection with.
```

Is there a better practice to this ? considering I'am trying to achieve 
the minimum code writing (redundancy).

> Note: this also applies for `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: I have tested this in instruments, still no issue but the test was only on one UIViewController, i need the ultimate test cases or if someone has already used such approach before could advise

Comment: I have been recently doing the same thing. I don't think this should generate any memory leak, just keep an eye on the profiler/graph. However, if you're only using this once then there's absolutely no need for this over architecture.

Comment: @MauricioChirino i agree, i am thinking about this for the future, as i would probably use this multiple times, as shown i would eventually inject the datasource with data, so i can use it around my application pretty fast without the overhead of writing the same dataSource over and over .

Comment: @MauricioChirino also imagine UnitTesting with this approach, i think could be really good

Comment: "Is this approach going to cause any memory leaks in the future ?" No by default, unless you did something that causes a retain cycle.

Comment: @AhmadF good but how about high memory usage graph ?  when it implemented in several places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Is this approach going to cause any memory leaks in the future ?

Not right now.
Your memory graph will look like: 
[image: memory graph]

So here no memory cycles and no reasons to leak memory.

**Important**. If you add reference from DataSource / Delegate on your viewController, make sure it is weak reference, otherwise you will create memory cycle.

**Note**. You can add strong references from DataSource / Delegate on collectionView, since collectionView have weak references on dataSource and delegate. So no cycle as well

#### Side note

Better to register cells in data source, since "only" data source know what types of cell will be used.

Comment: In general using separate classes for dataSources/Delegates is good approach. You can even go further and create generic variant which will work with most of your tables / collections

Comment: can you give me a link to read about the  generic variant you mean

Comment: @MohmmadS try google `swift generic uitableviewdatasource`. Here plenty of articles and I don't have any recommendations

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vague, but in general, that is a very common practice. We use this pattern a lot in our company:

```
class MainCollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var dataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource = self
    lazy var delegate: UICollectionViewDelegate = self

    static func with(dataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource, delegate: UICollectionViewDelegate) -> MainCollectionViewController {
        let vc = MainCollectionViewController()
        vc.dataSource = dataSource
        vc.delegate = delegate

        return vc
    }
}

extension MainCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // code
}

extension MainCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    // code
}
```

The two primary uses are for unit testing and for passing data to the view controller. The tester can inject custom data source and delegate at test time:

```
let testVC = MainCollectionViewController.with(dataSource: ..., delegate: ...)
// do test
```

Or passing data to it:

```
// In another view controller
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? MainCollectionViewController {
        destinationVC.dataSource = ...
        destinationVC.delegate = ...
    }
}
```

As to memory leak, this pattern is generally safe but obviously someone will run into a memory problem once in a while. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: why `UIViewController` not `NSObject` ?

Comment: + this one is different i guess from the one  i use however +1 for the effort and idea